# How do I reset the scores for the Conductor and DJ Grooves?

Tags: a-hat-in-time

In Chapter 2 of a Hat in Time, I have gotten myself stuck in a situation where DJ Grooves has a score lead of nearly 300 points over the Conductor.

I have replayed the Conductor's acts multiple times to try and improve my score, but the [large point difference between the two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03emK.jpg) has made it impossible to close the gap.

I checked my save file under `\HatinTime\HatinTimeGame\SaveData\slot1.hat` to see if I could manually reset my level scores, but the file format doesn't lend itself to easy editing.

**Is there any way to reset my Chapter 2 level scores to change who wins the film contest?**

Comment: **For others with this issue**: I was able to drastically increase my score for Act 4 (Train Rush) by using the Time Stopper Hat (slows down time) with the Fast Hatter Badge (decrease hat cooldown). My time bonus was enough to [boost my level score to over 1000](https://i.imgur.com/NEvvU2L.jpg).